# sort two columns in a text file with numpy.lexsort

Tags: python, sorting, numpy

I have a text file contain two columns and I want to sort the first column from smaller values to larger values and sort the second column according to the first column and then save it to the the same file. I used this method but did not work

```
data4 = np.loadtxt('crate&J.txt')
a = data4[:,0]
b = data4[:,1]
ind = np.lexsort((b,a))
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lexsort don't sort array, it returns indices. Say for example from docs:

```
>>> first_names = ('Heinrich', 'Galileo', 'Gustav')
>>> surnames =    ('Hertz',    'Galilei', 'Hertz')
>>> data = np.array([first_names, surnames])
>>> ind = np.lexsort(data)
>>> data[:, ind]
array([['Galileo', 'Gustav', 'Heinrich'],
       ['Galilei', 'Hertz', 'Hertz']],
      dtype='|S8')
```

so I suppose for your case you need

```
ind = np.lexsort(data.T[[1,0], :]) # you sort columns, not rows, second row first
np.savetxt('crate&J.txt', data4[ind,:])
```

Comment: I made these commands >>> ind = np.lexsort(data)
>>> np.savetxt('crate&J.txt', data[ind,:]) but the output file contain only 2 rows however I have 50000 rows. Do you have another way to do that sort?

Comment: @user2154410 standard disclaimer then, if you found an answer youseful and serving your need, you can consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it